# Bipartite Graph theory- find pairwise overlap (shared edge) from bipartite adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, discrete-mathematics, adjacency-matrix

I have a bipartite graph stored in an adjacency matrix ***A*** (100*1900), 100 rows, 1900 columns. 
   Simply, I denote 100 rows representing factorA, 1900 columns representing factorB. The graph tells the connection between 100 factorA and 1900 factorB, thus it is a bipartite graph.

Thus, the matrix is |factorA|*|factorB|, the dimension of the matrix is 100*1900.

I need to find the pairwise overlap between factorB. 
  A way of doing so is a get ***A*** and transpose of ***A***, denote as ***T(A)***.

Then get **A' = T(A)*A**, so **A'** will be 100*100 matrix, then the items ***A'[i,j]*** corresponds to the number of factorB shared by factorA ***i***, and factorA ***j***.

Why is the above algorithm working ? Any reference publication or mathematical proof could be given ?

Comment: Can you describe what you're doing in more detail? Right now, I have no idea what T(A) is, how you computed it, why you tried to do this, or even what it means to "work." This seems like an interesting problem, but without more details I don't think you'll be able to get any good answers.

Comment: Furthermore, adjacency matrices are typically square. Are you referring to a node-edge incidence matrix? Or is this the adjacency matrix for a bipartite graph?

Comment: The transpose of adjacency matrix. You know the transpose of a matrix ?

Comment: @TimothyShields Yes, I mean a bipartite graph. Edges are between 100 factorA and 1900 factorB.

Comment: @TimothyShields I just want to know why it works, a reference or a mathematical proof would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A' = A * transpose(A).

A'[i,j] is the inner product of the ith row of A and the jth row of A. Suppose these two look like the following:

row(A,i) = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
row(A,j) = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

The element-wise product of these two is

row(A,i) .* row(A,j) = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

The inner product of the two rows is the sum of these values, 2. This is the intuition for why A'[i,j] is the number of shared connections between row i and row j.

If you look at transpose(A) * A, you will similarly be able to find shared connections between columns.

Comment: So T(A)*A does give A', where A'[i,j] means the factorB shared factorA i and j ? could you please give a proof or a reference in a link ?

Comment: @ToBeGeek This basically was a proof. How is this not sufficient? I have no reference or link for you - this is really very simple linear algebra.

Comment: the A' is supposed to be 100*100, right? I would like to have a formal written work if you can. @TimothyShields

Comment: @ToBeGeek A' = A * transpose(A). A is 100 by 1900. transpose(A) is 1900 by 100. Therefore A' is 100 by 100. -- If you're still having difficulty, I think you may be in over your head. Again, this is simple linear algebra. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Basic_operations

Comment: Thank you so much, I will think of writing the formally.  @TimothyShields

Comment: @ToBeGeek By the way, on Stack Overflow you should mark an answer as the solution if you decide it is. Figured I'd tell you because you're new here.